# How delete a embed editing a message Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I want to edit a message deleting the existing Embed. I tried

```
await message.edit(content="New Message", embed=None)
```

but the embed doesn't disappear. What should i do?

Comment: Is the content changing?

Comment: Yes but not the Embed

Comment: According to the API it should be removed by the way you are already using it. Maybe try to also use `suppress=True` ? EDIT: But for this option you also need `manage_messages` permission in the channel

Comment: Thank you. I will try